# compiling ilixi on ubuntu.

Tags: c++, g++

please sorry if I put this question but I don't know how to fix this. I never used c++ before if not for some hello world project. I need to compile ilixi on ubuntu. I already installed all the dependency and autogen don't complain again missing dependency.

At the moment in which I run

```
make
```

I receive this error:

```
Surface.cpp: In member function 'void ilixi::Surface::setGeometry(int, int, int, int)':
Surface.cpp:157:44: error: in C++98 'r' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
 DFBRectangle r = { x, y, width, height };
                                        ^
Surface.cpp: In member function 'void ilixi::Surface::flip(const ilixi::Rectangle&)':
Surface.cpp:223:53: error: in C++98 'rect' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
             DFBRectangle rect = { 0, 0, w, r.y1 };
                                                 ^
Surface.cpp:229:68: error: in C++98 'rect' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
             DFBRectangle rect = { 0, r.y2 + 1, w, h - r.y2 - 1 };
                                                                ^
Surface.cpp:235:70: error: in C++98 'rect' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
             DFBRectangle rect = { 0, r.y1, r.x1, r.y2 - r.y1 + 1 };
                                                                  ^
Surface.cpp:241:85: error: in C++98 'rect' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
             DFBRectangle rect = { r.x2 + 1, r.y1, w - r.x2 - 1, r.y2 - r.y1 + 1 };
                                                                                 ^
```

I think this is related to some compiler variant of c++, because I'm trying to comile version 1.0.0 of ilixi and I think that cannot be an errror like this in the code of a released library. I would so stick on C++98 and changing it. Can someone tell me what kind of c++ dialect I need to use?

This is the only reference that I found with an error similar to mine. I tried to change the makefile for that kind of dialect but without any luck

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-std=c++11` to the gcc command line. The code is using uniform initialization, which is a C++11 feature. You will need a fairly recent version of gcc, the latest 4.8.x or 4.9.x or newer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile your application using C++11 standard. First of all, make sure to have at least gcc 4.7.

So, in order to compile your code, you should have something like `gcc -Wall **-std=c++11** -o test test.cpp`.

In a Makefile, search for something like this: `CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, gcc version is: gcc version 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6). I tried to place that is Makefile, it don't work. The system is using autogen for configure the program. I think that it would be better to put the param in some configuration file for autogen. I don't understand... http://ilixi.org/index.php?id=install-from-source-on-host paragraph: Installing ilixi there's the ./autogen.sh --enable-fusiondale --enable-fusionsound --enable-sawman --with-examples --prefix=/opt/dfb . Seen that they use autogen shouldn't be the params already right?

Answer (score 0):

INSTALL file tells you this:

> Briefly, the shell commands `./configure; make; make install' should
>   configure, build, and install this package.

Make sure you have them installed and then try to run ./configure, which will check for missing libs.

./configure

make && sudo make install

Autogen should also work if you have the prerequisites.

Comment: Sorry but... As you should know autogen.sh and ./configure act in the same way as soon as you have all the prerequisites. The problem is that it fail to build because it need to have some kind of parameter that is not actually satisfied.